# I need to add three backgrounds to the section element

Tags: html, css

So I am working on an assignment for class, and I have to add three backgrounds to the section element of the page.

One of these is a background image, which I was able to get to show up in the correct placement.

The other two are identical gradients positioned on the left and bottom edges of the section element.

However when I attempt to add the gradient code, it attempts to change the layout/color of the background image already there.

How do I add these gradients to the section element without overwriting the image?

attemps:

```
section { 
background-image:url(corner.png); 
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
background-position:bottom left; 
background-image: 
linear-gradient(left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% ); 
background-position:left; 
background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% ); background-position:bottom; 
}
```

Comment: show us the code of attempts, in a fiddle or codepen :) img and gradient will stack in background, tuning can be achieve too with repeat, size, position ....

Comment: section {
background-image:url(corner.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom left;

background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% );
background-position:left;

background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% );
background-position:bottom;
}

Comment: Sorry still a noob, is there a way I need to format the code so it looks like it would for me?

Comment: i edited your post (edit yourself and look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all together at once, more like:

```
section { 
background-image:
  url(corner.png),    
  linear-gradient(to left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% ),
   linear-gradient(to left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% );
background-position:
  bottom left,
  left, 
  bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That just makes the working corner.png image disappear. I basically have to have the corner.png image in the corner (obviously) and the gradient going vertical down the side of the element on the left, with the same gradient going horizontal at the bottom of the gradient.

Comment: change order so gradient do not overlay the image . see for meore accurate infos : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering

Comment: #corner{
background-image:url(corner.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:bottom left;
}

#left{
background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% );
background-position:left;
}

#bottom{
background-image: linear-gradient(left bottom, rgba(170, 90, 27, 0.7), rgba(16, 77, 61, 0.7) 2%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 5% );
background-position:bottom;
}

This was one attempt where I tried to use the div id to define left, bottom, and corner, but it does nothing either.

Comment: is missing in your original code : to in front of direction in linear gardients, linear-gradient(**to** bottom left , ....

Comment: i got part of it to show, but i need the one on the left of the element to behave like background-repeat: repeat-y, and the one on the bottom as repeat-x. I need basically 2 identical gradients, but I need one down the left edge and one across the bottom edge.

Comment: That didnt work...lol...that covered the entire element in the gradient repeatedly. I just need it to cover the left edge, almost like a border. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: can you make a fiddle or codepen of what you did and a screen of the result you look for. it is all about tunning each image/gradients

Comment: How can I post the screen? I'm just trying this.

Comment: use any free image hoster you find and link it here :)

Comment: [url=http://postimg.org/image/n1z2i6dip/][img]http://s24.postimg.org/n1z2i6dip/Capture1.png[/img][/url]

[url=http://postimg.org/image/qk6h0tp0x/][img]http://s24.postimg.org/qk6h0tp0x/Capture2.png[/img][/url]

Comment: One shows the header, which I need to understand why the background image is off....

Comment: And the other shows the main section where I'm trying to create the 3 backgrounds.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm stuck.

Comment: @JDP3 Hello, you could dispatch your different backgrounds into different containers :  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vIcit